# Obtaining a tractable expression for P(X<2Y)

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

The joint probability of the bivariate random vector $(X,Y)$ is given by $f_{X, Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Compute $P(X<2Y)$.

My attempt: I made the obvious transformation to polar coordinates to obtain $f_{R, \theta}(r,t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}re^{-r}$. This is pleasant; $R$ and $\theta$ are independent of each other, with $\theta$ being uniform on $[0, 2\pi]$ and $R$ being a gamma. Since we have defined $X = R \cos\theta$ and $Y = R \sin\theta, X<2Y$ whenever $\cos\theta<2\sin\theta$, or $\cot\theta<2$ (edit: this is a blunder, see below). The uniformity of $\theta$ over $[0, 2\pi]$ means that $P(X<2Y)$ is the total length of the intervals on which $\cot\theta<2$, divided by $2\pi$.

...is that as far as a straightforward computation goes? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I know no way of numerically evaluating what I found here. Is there a better way to solve this, which obtains a more tractable expression for the probability?

Edit: there is a blunder in my analysis: $\cos\theta<2\sin\theta$ does not imply $\cot\theta<2$! I got sloppy with my signs.

Comment: For the remaining calculation, plot $\cot \theta$ vs $\theta$.

Comment: Is it not easier than all of that?  The bivariate density is "radially symmetric" around $(0,0)$.  So isn't $P(X<k Y)=1/2$ for any $k$?

Comment: @JimB, my understanding of what you said is that there is a bijective map (more precisely, a reflection matrix) between two points across the line y = ax, such that both points have the same density. Is that it?

Comment: @jimb... You really ought to expand your comment as an answer...

Comment: Bijectivity is not sufficient: you need the map to preserve probability (which that reflection does).  Perhaps the easiest way to see the result is to rotate the coordinates so that the event $X\lt 2Y$ becomes $X^\prime < 0$ and observe the distribution is symmetric in $X^\prime$ (with zero chance that $X^\prime=0$). But if you were to continue your own analysis by **drawing a picture** of the integration region, you would see at once it's a half-plane and immediately write down the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the error in my original method. I'd appreciate feedback on my solution! We will solve this in generality; that is, we will show, as @JimB asserted, that $P(X<kY) = 1/2$ for *any* k.

The working in my original analysis holds to a point; we do have to find the length of the interval in $[0, 2\pi]$ over which  $f(t) = \cos t - k \sin t < 0$. First, note that $\cos t - k \sin t = 0$ if and only if $\cot t = k$. Because $\cot t$ takes all real values exactly once on each of the intervals $(0, \pi)$ and $(\pi, 2\pi)$, we have exactly two roots of the equation $f(t) = 0$, and they have the form $a$ and $a+\pi$ where $a \in (0, \pi)$.

$f(t) = \cos t - k \sin t$ is continuous and has no other roots, and hence takes either purely negative or purely positive values on the interval $(a, a+\pi)$. But note that $\pi$ is on this interval, and certainly $f(\pi) = -1$ and therefore is negative. Therefore, $f(t)$ is negative on $(a, a+\pi)$.

Also, $f(0) = f(2\pi) = 1$, and once again by continuity and the fact that there are no other roots of $f(t) = 0$, $f(t)$ is positive on the intervals $[0, a)$ and $(a+\pi, 2\pi]$.

Hence, $f(t) = \cos t - k \sin t < 0$ over $(a, a+\pi)$, an interval of length $\pi$. Hence  $P(X<kY) = \frac{\pi}{2\pi} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Edit: Slicker proof. Express $\cos t - k \sin t$ as $\sqrt{1+k^2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\cos t - \frac{k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\sin t)= \sqrt{1+k^2}(\cos a\cos t - \sin a \sin t) = \sqrt{1+k^2}(\cos (t+a))$

for some a. This is clearly a scaled and shifted cosine function, and hence is negative over an interval of length $\pi$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somewhat in the spirit of the video listed in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267065/how-to-visualize-the-circle-triangle-probability-problem.

And it is a bit of a handwaving proof based on the fact that the bivariate pdf is radially symmetric about $(0,0)$.  So no matter what value of $k$ is used for determining $Pr(X < k Y)$ the result is always 1/2 as the plane defined by $X = k Y$ divides the pdf into two equal parts:

[image: Animation of slicing bivariate pdf in half]

Comment: A crucial part of the argument deals with the fact that the parts are *not* equal.  There's the common boundary to consider (this is where you need to observe the distribution is continuous).  IMHO, the animation makes this post unreadable: I can't bear to watch it for more than a couple of iterations, which is around one second.

Comment: @whuber.  I'll fix the animations to be smoother as I certainly don't want it to be unbearable to you.  I must say that I don't understand that "the parts are not equal.  There's the common boundary to consider (this is where you need to observe the distribution is continuous."  I'll think about that more to see if I can figure out what you mean.